# TWA shows address bar even if assetlink is correct

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I'm using the PWABuilder to create the apk but whenever I build it, change the fingerprint and install the app, the address bar always shows up.

I used the "Asset links tool" to check if everything was correct and it seems to be so, assetlink fingerprint is the exact same.
I've had this issue only after the latest update of PWABuilder, i'm not sure if it's related.

Website manifest and assetlink: https://github.com/Specy/specy.github.io/tree/master/skyMusic
Website URL: https://specy.github.io/skyMusic/
Asset links: https://specy.github.io/skyMusic/.well-known/assetlinks.json
APK: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/771432833034092554/878028887584550952/Sky_Music_Nightly.apk

I tried on two different devices too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue, the .well-known/assetlinks.json file needs to be placed in the root of the URL, not the root of the app, in this case my app was at /skyMusic/ so we I thought I had to place it there, while I had to place it in /

Answer (score 1):

have you tried checking the logs using the following command?

> adb logcat -v brief | grep -e OriginVerifier -e digital_asset_links

most likely there's an issue (perhaps with the package name) in your asset link file.

also worth checking you can actually view the assetlink file by browsing to the url (https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json) if you can't see that from your device then it wont work.

Comment: I forgot to mention the fix, apparently the assetlink file has to be in the root of the URL, not the root of the app. In this case my app Is at /skyMusic/ so I placed the asset link relative to that, while it has to be placed in /